# How to make a parametric configuration file?

Tags: java, configuration-files, apache-commons-config

I have a question about configuration files.
Is it possible to create a `file.properties` in java (example with Apache Commons Configuration) as:

```
name = tom
surname = donald
free string = my favourite color is + paramFromJavaCode
```

where *paramFromJavaCode* is dinamically set from Java code?
I hope I was clear, thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to create a .properties file in Java code?

Comment: I have already created it, but I don't know if that I have written is possible @Jazzepi

Comment: You can write anything you want to a file using normal Java operations; it's not clear what the issue is.

Comment: I'd like to write a config file manually, but some string could be handled from Java code so, exists a syntax to chain parameter to string in _file.properties_? @Dave Newton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to create a .properties file programmatically you can do it this way. I added a section on how to add something to the marmot string. That's pretty basic Java string manipulation though!

```
public class WritePropertiesFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String customString = " are great!";

        try {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.setProperty("favoriteAnimal", "marmot" + customString);
            properties.setProperty("favoriteContinent", "Antarctica");
            properties.setProperty("favoritePerson", "Nicole");

            File file = new File("test2.properties");
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            properties.store(fileOut, "Favorite Things");
            fileOut.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Which will output

```
#Favorite Things
#Sat Feb 24 00:10:53 PST 2007
favoriteContinent=Antarctica
favoriteAnimal=marmot are great!
favoritePerson=Nicole
```

Comment: Ok thank you, but is it possible to set first the string "marmot" manually in config file and then chain it a string from Java code?

Comment: You want to add something to the "marmot" string? Like "marmot is great"?

Comment: Yes. "marmot" added manully and "is great" setted from java code to getting later the string "marmot is great" @Jazzepi

Answer (score 0):

you can create it like:

```
free string = my favourite color is %s
```

and later in java code:

```
propval = String.format(propval, paramFromJavaCode);
```

for this line.